# Can you automate the creation of low disk space alarms in AWS Cloudwatch through Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch

I have multiple accounts with Windows EC2 instances that are built by Terraform. I would like to create an alarm for each of the "LogicalDisk % Free Space" metrics that we have in Cloudwatch, but I can't find any way for Terraform to see that information. I am completely lost on how to iterate over the information, because the Cloudwatch Alarm requires instance-id, ami-id, instance type, and drive name (like C:, D:, etc.).

The metric itself has all of this information store plainly, but how can I access that through Terraform??

I have a data block to pull windows instance information, but it can't pull drive letters. I created another variable that lists ALL possible drive letters, but I don't know if I can nest a for loop in any way to go over both (even if I did, it would create some useless alarms because not all drives have all letters).

```
variable "windows_instances" {
  type = set(string)
  default = ["dc01", "dc02", "profile", "home"]
}

variable "drive_letter" {   
  type = list   
  default = ["C:" , "D:" , "E:"]
}

locals {
    instance_ids = data.aws_instances.all_windows_instances.ids
}

data "aws_instances" "all_windows_instances" {
    for_each = var.windows_instances
    instance_tags = {
        Name = "server-${each.key}-${tenant}"
    }
}

data "aws_instance" "instance_details" {
  for_each = toset(local.instance_ids)
  instance_id = each.value
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "windows_disk_alarm" {
    for_each = toset(local.instance_ids)
    alarm_name = "LowDiskSpace-${data.aws_instance.instance_details[each.value].tags["Name"]}"
    comparison_operator = "LessThanOrEqualToThreshold"
    threshold = "20"
    evaluation_periods = "1"
    statistic = "Average"
    period = "600"
    metric_name = "LogicalDisk % Free Space"
    namespace = "CWAgent"
    alarm_description = <<-EOT
    .
    .
    .
    _______________________________________________
    _______________________________________________
    # ${data.aws_instance.instance_details[each.value].tags["Name"]}
    is **low on disk space**.

    Please investigate!
    _______________________________________________
    _______________________________________________
    .
    .
    .
    EOT
    alarm_actions = [data.aws_sns_topic.sns_topic_arn.arn]
    dimensions = {
        InstanceId = data.aws_instance.instance_details[each.value].id
        InstanceType = data.aws_instance.instance_details[each.value].instance_type
        Instance = DRIVE LETTER VALUE
        ImageId = data.aws_instance.instance_details[each.value].ami
        objectname = "LogicalDisk" 
        }
}
```

Comment: Do you have the [CloudWatch agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/install-CloudWatch-Agent-commandline-fleet.html) already installed?

Comment: Yes! The agent is installed and is placing the metrics into Cloudwatch.

Comment: Ok, so this only shows the variables and data sources, is there any code for metrics and alerts?

Comment: I didn't originally include it because it didn't work at all, but I've now updated my question with what I have. This code works for Linux instances because they don't require the "instance" (aka drive letter) dimension.

Comment: In my experience I never had to supply the drive letter on any alarm ... My recommendation: first create a test alarm manually in the console, fine tune to suit 
 your needs, then import it using terraform  [generate-config-out](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/import/generating-configuration) that way you can compare and see the difference with what you been doing